# how to hide my iOS 8 keyboard extension in certain app from keyboard popup list when global key is clicked

Tags: iphone, ios8, ios8-extension, ios-keyboard-extension

I an writing a keyboard extension for iOS8. There is bug in 2 apps and I want to hide my iOS 8 keyboard extension keyboard popup list of the 2 app when user click the global key. I saw some third keyboard can do this.

Comment: I believe that this is impossible, and that there is another explanation for the behavior you've seen. Could you please name the keyboards and the apps they don't show up in? Note that keyboards can specify their capabilities, and if the textfield isn't compatible with them, it won't appear.

Answer (score 0):

App can disallow using extension keyboard by [shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier:), but keyboard can't disallow using an app.I think it's that you saw.